# How to pass the inputs of the argparser args to arguments to another function?

Tags: python, function, program-entry-point, argparse, paramiko

I am writing a program which basically logs into the remote server(Linux) and execute few commands. For that I need to get the inputs like "Server IP ", "Username", and "password" from the command line. For which am using the `argparse` module. My code looks something like this:

```
import sys
import argparse
import getpass
import re
from time import gmtime, strftime

import paramiko
try:
    import interactive
except ImportError:
    from . import interactive

def do_connect(esxi):
        """Connect to host in the esxi host"""
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='DEV Installer App')
    parser.add_argument("--esxiIP", help="Mention the Esxi Host IP", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--userName", help="Enter the UserName of the Host", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--password", help="Enter the Password", required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

What I am trying to do here is , I have a function for connecting to the remote server and am getting the inputs using `argparse` in the `main()` function. I need to pass these input arguments to the `do_connect` function. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The `self` argument on `do_connect()` looks out of place here; it is not a method and you are not using the parameter at all.

Answer (score 1):

`args` is a `Namespace` instance object with attributes for each command-line argument. The arguments are based on the option switch, unless you give it a different name explicitly.

In this case, you'll have `args.esxiIP`, `args.userName` and `args.password` attributes, which you can then pass on to another function. If your function takes just the `esxiIP` argument, pass that on:

```
do_connect(args.esxiIP)
```

If it needs more arguments, explicitly pass these on too.

Demo:

```
>>> args = parser.parse_args('--esxiIP 10.20.30.40 --userName foo --password bar'.split())
>>> args
Namespace(esxiIP='10.20.30.40', password='bar', userName='foo')
>>> args.esxiIP
'10.20.30.40'
>>> args.userName
'foo'
>>> args.password
'bar'
```